# ssh-agent on CentOS 6.5 keeps "disabling" itself

Tags: ssh, centos, git, ssh-agent

I recently installed `git` on my CentOS 6.5 system. During the process I setup a `key/pair` for `GitHub` so I don't have to enter a password for every `git` process. I did this by adding the `rsa` file to `ssh-agent` which worked fine. About an hour or so later I received this message while doing a `git push`:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I did:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

which started it back up again and then re-added the `rsa` file again to the `ssh-agent`

So I guess there's a setting that is turning off `ssh-agent` every so often. Coming from Ubuntu, I'm not used to this behavior so what configuration do I need to change in order to keep `ssh-agent` ON and persist the keys?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that turns off the ssh-agent.  Next time it happens, check the value of the environment variable `$SSH_AGENT_PID`, and see if the process is still running.  Maybe something else is killing your ssh agent?